# AngularJs ManyToOne Json

Tags: angularjs, json, hibernate, rest

Can you help me with some issue on Json serialize ManyToOne relation object on JAX-RS WebService context ?
I have 2 tables Role and User linked by OneToMany and ManyToOne , respectively, whit Hibernate annotation:
**Role Entity**

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
public class Role implements ...
{
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<User> user = new ArrayList<User>();    
    .....
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "role")
    public List<User2015> getUser2015s() {
        return this.user2015s;
    }
}
```

**User Entity**

```
@Entity
public class User implements ...
{
    @JsonBackReference
    private Role role;
    .....
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Role_Id", nullable = false)
    public Role getRole() {
        return this.role;
    }

}
```

I used jackson annotation to solve infinite recursively overflow on json mapping

To complete scenario i have listAll() method on **rest endpoint User** as:

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public List<User> listAll(@QueryParam("start") Integer startPosition,
            @QueryParam("max") Integer maxResult) {
    TypedQuery<User2015> findAllQuery = em
            .createQuery(
            "<b>SELECT DISTINCT u FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.role ORDER BY u.id</b>",
....
    final List<User> results = findAllQuery.getResultList();


return results;
}
```

and  method listAll() on **rest endpoint Role** as:

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public List<Role> listAll(@QueryParam("start") Integer startPosition,   @QueryParam("max") Integer maxResult) {
    TypedQuery<Role> findAllQuery = em.createQuery(
   "<b>SELECT DISTINCT r FROM Role r LEFT JOIN FETCH r.users ORDER BY   r.id", Role.class</b>);
.......
    if(results != null)
        return results;
    else
        return null;
}
```

and till now all seems well ... inspecting returned **results** each list elements have all object populated (each user have role object filled and vice versa)

Problem began using **angularjs factory $resources**

**factory User**

```
angular.module('backend').factory('UserResource', function($resource){
var resource = $resource('rest/users/:Userd',{UserId:'@id'},
                        {'queryAll':{method:'GET',isArray:true},
                        'query':{method:'GET',isArray:false},
                        'update':{method:'PUT'}});
return resource;
```

});

**factory Role**

```
angular.module('backend').factory('RoleResource', function($resource){
var resource = $resource('rest/roles/:RoleId',{RoleId:'@id'},
                        {'queryAll':{method:'GET',isArray:true},
                        'query':{method:'GET',isArray:false},
                        'update':{method:'PUT'}});
return resource;
```

});

Invoking rest role queryall() returned Json is right as expected:

```
[{"id":1,"codice":"POS","descrizione":"Point Of Sale",<b>"users"</b>:[{"id":1,"username":"doe","codice":"30030","isEnable":false,"dataCreazione":1 ...
```

each role has many users

**but on other side invoking rest user queryall() Json produced missing role object information** :

```
    [{"id":1,"username":"doe","codice":"30030mella","isEnable":false,"dataCreazione":1450738800000,"idReale":1,"dataExpire":"2099-12-31"},
{"id":2,"username":"foo","codice" ....
```

I would expected (and i need) **to have Role information for each user**.

Some suggestion are very appreciate.
What am I doing wrong ??

Answer (score 0):

With `@JsonManagedReference`/`@JsonBackReference` this is not possible.

> Before Jackson 2.0, handling of cyclic object graphs (or, more
>   generally, that of shared references) was limited to specific case of
>   parent/child (bi-directional) references.

see http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureObjectIdentity where the alternative `@JsonIdentityInfo` is presented too:

> It can be used on classes (to indicate that properties of that type should have feature enabled) as well as on individual properties (to support cases where type itself can not be annotated; or to use different id generation sequence).

```js
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")
public class User {

    private Role role;

    public Role getRole() {
        return this.role;
    }
}

//////

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")
public class Role {

    private List<User> user = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<User> getUser() {
        return user;
    }
}
```